# Running node in command line w/o sudo

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, path, installation

I installed NodeJS on my Ubuntu server and now I'm wondering why I can't use it by simply typing "node". "nodejs" works fine, but only "node" should work, too, right?
"sudo node" works as well, so I thought this might be a problem with the PATH, but the PATH variables are identical:

```
root@myserver:/# node -v
-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory
root@myserver:/# sudo node -v
v8.2.1
root@myserver:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
root@myserver:/# sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past. I started installing Node like this on Ubuntu I have never had any issues with just using the `node` command, it has just worked:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Let me know if this works. You can read more about it here: [https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it, just pasted your commands, didn't even remove the package before :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install using `apt-get`? This is not recommended. Remove `nodejs` package and install from `nodejs.org`, https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

You might also want to consider using something like `nvm` to manage your node versions, https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 1):

Using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) you can solve this issue, and as a plus, it gives you the ability to install multiple node versions and bind the `node` command to whichever version you prefer

After installing nvm:

```
nvm install vX.Y.Z
nvm alias default vX.Y.Z
node -v // vX.Y.Z
```